Saved or stored list of all of the open files in Visual Studio Code’s current Workspace
With the latest edition, Visual Studio Code team has introduced the feature of creating multiple workspaces and create workspaces for files that complement the contents of all of the other files in that folder, or files that belong together as they represent a single, larger ongoing project.
However, whenever I try to create a new workspace, the updated installation of the Visual Studio Code demands that I should start afresh and then start adding files to those workspaces one by one. I have been using Visual Studio Code since 2017, and right now, I have approximately 40+ files open in my single workspace. It would be a truly cumbersome task manually storing the paths of all of the files in a text file just to then locate them individually to place them in appropriate folders. I would like to know where does Visual Studio Code keep a record of all of the open files in the current workspace so that I would be able to fetch the list of open files from there instead of storing their paths one by one.
So far, my searches on the Internet have resulted in the following futile attempts to find the correct directory containing the current vscode.workspace file:
$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json
In the aforementioned directory, I am able to find the settings.json file; however, I am not able to find the .workspace file to find all of the currently open files. Any assistance in finding the stored list of all of the open files would be greatly appreciated.

The files should be contained in the /'workspaceStorage'. You could try and reinstall VSCode, to see if that fixes the issue.
